# Show Binlog retention on MySQL prior to version 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysqlbinlog

How can I see the current Binlog retention setting for MySQL 5.5.53?

I know that version 5.6 has the command:

```
CALL mysql.rds_show_configuration;
```

Is there an equivalent for versions prior to 5.6?

I ran this command but I am not sure if this is correct:

```
show variables like "expire_logs_days";
```

Results:
Variable_name    | value
expire_logs_days    0

Comment: don't you think that is time to switch t a newer version, 5.5 is deprecated sinse December 3, 2018

Comment: yes, it is, but this is not my usual project. someone else's.